How to keep latest calculated value until there is a change in a variable?
How do I create a measure that only calculates the output when there is a change in variable A and when there isnt keeps the latest value (example in the image attached).example of measure



better
check




image
has


the
table



Lots of things and nothing did it.

you can try to create a column
Column=
VAR _first =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[variable A] ) )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[variable A] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[variable A] )
                && 'Table'[date] = _first
        ),
        'Table'[variable A]
    )
        / MAXX (
            FILTER (
                'Table',
                'Table'[variable A] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[variable A] )
                    && 'Table'[date] = _first
            ),
            'Table'[variable B]
        )


